# ModuleNotFoundError in Code Runner, but works fine in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

When I right click the file in VS Code and click on Run Python File in Terminal - it runs perfectly fine and gives me the desired outputs.

However, when I click Run Code or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> it opens up the Output tab next to the terminal and produces no output - just an error message stating that the module flask does not exist.

I do not understand this, since the flask package is installed.

I created venv and deleted it. That flask was working fine until yesterday. Now, its not working unless I run the py file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your flask package installed in a python virtual environment, you will need to set the python binary from your virtual environment as the interpreter for your script.

You can do this in VS Code by going to **Command Palette > Python: Select Interpreter** and selecting the path to the python binary located in your virtual environment directory.

For example, if your virtual environment directory is named `.venv` and is located in your VS Code project folder, the binary location will be `.venv/bin/python` for Mac/Linux or it will be `.venv\Scripts\python.exe` for Windows.

However, setting this will only work for running in integrated Terminal, not with Run Code (assuming this is using the extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)).

When executing the python script using Run Code, Code Runner initiates its own terminal environment and runs your code there. The output from that is in Output tab. Code Runner does not activate your virtual environment there by default, instead looks for python binary in your system path. As a result, any packages you have in your virtual environment will not be accessible, which explains the ModuleNotFoundError.

To fix this, you need to configure executor map for Code Runner in your VS Code settings (ideally at workspace level) and provide the path to python binary from your virtual environment.

Example below is for Mac/Linux. If Windows, change the map value to `PATH_TO_PROJECT\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -u`. Replace `PATH_TO_PROJECT` with the actual path to your VS Code project folder.

```json
"settings": {
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "PATH_TO_PROJECT/.venv/bin/python -u",
    }
}
```